# Custom variable filtering from another model

Tags: yii

So basically I have 3 models namely Credits, Employee and User.

Credits belongs to Employee model via employee_id column and Employee belongs to the User model via user_id.

In Employee model I added a custom variable $fullName which retrieves the name of the employee from the User table.

```
private $_fullName = null;

public function getFullName()
{
    if ($this->_fullName === null && $this->usr !== null) {
        $this->_fullName = $this->usr->last_name . ', ' . $this->usr->first_name. ' ' . $this->usr->middle_name;
    }
    return $this->_fullName;
}

public function setFullName($value)
{
    $this->_fullName = $value;
}

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'usr'=>array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'User', 'employee_id'),
    );
}
```

Now in Credits model, I reused the same variable $fullName and made its value to employee.fullName so that I can access credits.fullName and use it in a cgridview. My problems is its working fine on the cgrid but I dont know how to filter the data using that custom variable. I need to know what I can use to compare $this->fullName from credits to do the filtering in the search function. One solution I can think of is directly relating the Credits table to the User table but I want to know if it is possible to just use the custom variable on the Employee model.

Credits model:

```
public function getFullName()
{
    if ($this->_fullName === null && $this->employee !== null) {
        $this->_fullName = $this->employee->fullName;
    }
    return $this->_fullName;
}
public function setFullName($value)
{
    $this->_fullName = $value;
}

public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'employee' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Employee', 'employee_id'),
    );
}

public function search()
{
    // Warning: Please modify the following code to remove attributes that
    // should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->with ='employee';

    ???????????? what to add here

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}
```

Cgridview:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id'=>'credits-grid',
'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
'filter'=>$model,
'columns'=>array(
        'fullName',
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well you must include in the with method the entity user and in the compare concat the fields name, in mysql is like

```
$criteria->with = array('employee' => array('with' => 'user'));
$criteria->compare('concat(user.firstname, \' \', user.lastname)', $this->fullName, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

add the compare method

```
$criteria->compare('employee.fullName', $this->fullName, true);
```

Comment: yeah. tried that one already but it doesnot make sense since there is no fullName column on the employee table.

Comment: and how or what you get of  this value? 
$this->employee->fullName

Comment: Employee model has custom variable fullName as I have said which retrieves, user.firstname user.middlename and user.lastname.